# sp_executesql processes uniqueidentifier-param with EntityCommandExecutionException but still acts like expected

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, dynamic-sql, entity-framework

I use a Azure DB(MS-Sql) and administrate the DB with Management Studio for SQL Server 2016. My Application is a simple C#/WPF-Application.

So here we go, this is my SProc:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StartChangeTrackingProcedure]
(
@UID uniqueidentifier
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO TBL_ChangeTrackerPerLoggedUser 
             VALUES (0,0,0,0,0, @UID)';
             PRINT @sql;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, '@UID uniqueidentifier', @UID = @UID
END
```

The TBL_ChangeTrackerPerLoggedUser's name is a bit confusing as it has nothing to do with the ordinary ChangeTracking-Mechanism, it is just a simple table where you can look up wether there were made any changes to DB or not (because Azure has no Query Notifications, right?). It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_ChangeTrackerPerLoggedUser](
[ChangedTemplates] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ChangedInstances] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ChangedWF] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ChangedUser] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ChangedDoc] [bit] NOT NULL,
[UserDependency] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_ChangeTrackerPerLoggedUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[UserDependency] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Next you'll see the call from Entitiy Framework, where LoggedUser.Instance.UsrID is a GUID:

```
 using (NCDBEntities DBContext = new NCDBEntities())
 {
     var uid = new SqlParameter("@UID", LoggedUser.Instance.UsrID);
     var res = DBContext.Database
               .SqlQuery<TBL_ChangeTrackerPerLoggedUser>
               ("StartChangeTrackingProcedure @UID", uid).ToList();
 }
```

Now, when i process this code I get an EntityCommandExecutionException telling me:

> Der Datenleser ist mit dem angegebenen Wert für 'NCDBModel.TBL_ChangeTrackerPerLoggedUser' nicht kompatibel. Ein Element vom Typ ('ChangedTemplates') weist keine entsprechende Spalte im gleichnamigen Datenleser auf.

Translated this means something like:

> Datareader is not compatible with the given value for 'NCDBModel.TBL_ChangeTrackerPerLoggedUser'. One element of type ('ChangedTemplates') has no actual column in equal named Datareader.

But when i take a look at DB at this point, SProc has been executed successfully:
[image: This is the result, as i expected...]

So...is there any advice or explanation you can provide to understand this kind of magic? Should i simply catch this Exception and act like it never happened? Sideeffects etc.? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an API that expects a result set ([`SqlQuery<...>(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx)) but your stored procedure produces no result set. Hence the error message. The error occurs on the client side, *after* your procedure has executed, to explain the 'magic' you see.

You have several alternatives:

- Use a non-query API, like [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx)
- have your stored procedure produce a result set, using the [`OUTPUT` clause of `INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql).
- [Map the stored procedure in EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I've chosen the ExecuteSQLCommand since at the moment i don't need any return value. My call looks like that:

   `using (NCDBEntities DBContext = new NCDBEntities())
    {
        var temp = DBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand 
        ("StartChangeTrackingProcedure @UID",
        new SqlParameter("@UID", LoggedUser.Instance.UsrID));
    }`

Comment: temp gets an '-1'-value what´s a bit weird but no exception is rising and the result is as expected. 
If anybody has any suggestions/recommendations feel free to comment, i´m still learning!